# Automatically copy contents from one webpage to other

Tags: automation, copy, monitoring, html

I need to copy the contents from a webpage every time if the contents get updated and paste it to another webpage. I can run selenium IDE every 5 minuets to refresh the webpage to check for new contents.

Is there any way to capture new contents and update it in another webpage?

Note: The target page would be of excel format(cells in webpage).

Source Page:

Red marked area is where the update happens. New line sits in the top.
[Source Page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/L7ugD.png)

Target image:
[Target Page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/thFYv.png)

Please help me to move in this regards. If above one is not possible, and if you could help me to export contents from source page to excel would also be fine. Thanks.

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: I tried with Bash commands, but it did not work out.

Comment: Please share the commands you tried, what you’ve got, and what you wanted to get instead.

Comment: I copy pasted the bash script which is similar to my requirement from a blog(thinking that I could modify it as per my needs).  But when I try to run I got "command not found" error in bash window

Comment: We can’t help you if you don’t share your code.